# What is the lifetime of the cache when using the property in an $http get?

Tags: angularjs, caching

If I set the $http.get to have a cache like this:

```
$http.get(url, { cache: true}).success(...);
```

Then where is the data stored. Is there an object I can check to see this data. Also what is the lifetime of the data? Would the data be lost when I reload a page in the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's keeping so while alive your html page, if the page has been closed or refreshed it will be removed,  if you want to clear your cache you should use [$cacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory) provider's `removeAll()` function, if you want cache which will be kept for a long time then you should use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`